# Looping through a JSON object's entries and through react state, getting 'state undefined'

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, get

Please forgive if I am way off target, but I am trying to set a component's state to a json object, so that I can render it with the component.

Here is what a currently have inside my component:

```
render: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {
        this.state.content = $.parseJSON(data);

    }.bind(this));

    return (
        <div>

            {Object.keys(this.state.content).map(function (key) {
                return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.content[key]}</div>;
            })}


        </div>
    );
```

With this code I currently get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Anyone have any insight as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the `this` inside the `$.get()` is not in the React's scope. And calling `setState()` inside render will throw an error. The following should help...

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      content: {},
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest()
  },

  serverRequest: function() {
    var _this = this
    $.get(this.props.source, function(data) {
      _this.state.content = $.parseJSON(data);

    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return ( < div >

      {
        Object.keys(this.state.content).map(function(key) {
          return <div > Key: {
            key
          }, Value: {
            this.state.content[key]
          } < /div>;
        })
      }


      < /div >
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: It still didn't work I'm afraid. I get the exact same error.
Also, I have another state that is set within the same function which works just fine. It's just the this.state.content that is not working.

Comment: @theJuls Did you try the `_this` approach?

Comment: I did :( I practically copied what you did there, and it didn't work.
I am also now messing around with it in different ways to see if it works, but still nothing.

Comment: Ohh never mind. I actually got it to work, with a few changes here and there :)
Thanks!